# When is mysql-client needed?

Tags: mysql

I have read a number of tutorials on installing MySQL, and I've noticed that many of them only discuss installing `mysql-server`, whereas some also discuss installing `mysql-client`. My main question is: when is it necessary to install `mysql-client`?

It seems that when I remove `mysql-client` from my system, I can still access `mysql-server` from the command line (simply by issuing `mysql -u root` -p). How is `mysql-server` accessible without `mysql-client` installed?

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? And what is in that package?

Comment: Linux distribution is Ubuntu 18.04. Are you referring to the `mysql-server` package?

Comment: Um, no? That's not the package you asked about. You asked about `mysql-client`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. As far as I know, it's the package you install for the MySQL client.

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql-client` package is a metapackage with no real files of its own (except for boilerplate copyright, etc.). Its sole purpose is to depend on the actual package containing the latest version of the MySQL client, which in bionic is `mysql-client-5.7`. Thus when you instal `mysql-client` on any version of Ubuntu, you will get the latest version of MySQL available, and when you upgrade Ubuntu to another major version, MySQL will also be upgraded. Which also means that if you remove this file and leave `mysql-client-5.7` then on upgrade either your client and server versions will be out of sync, or the upgrade will fail with dependency problems.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when you install the `mysql-server` package, a MySQL client is automatically installed:

```
~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libevent-core-2.1-6 *mysql-client-5.7* mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
```

Hence why it is often only recommended to install the `mysql-server` package (without separately installing `mysql-client`).

**EDIT**

So, I'm guessing the `mysql-client` package is really only necessary if the client is all you need (for connecting to a remove server).